# How to give more place for svg animation?

Tags: css, animation, svg

Yes, the task is a little weird. On `hover` each item has to scale.
The center-left item works stable. The top and left are almost fine too, but the top corner is cropped. The right items scale wrong, only on hover near the center of all SVG.
Like they have no place where to scale.
I tried to change width-height, it didn't help.
What's the property, that can fix it?

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/alexiusgrey/pen/OJjENGL)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: I suppose you can fix it by using a [viewBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) attribute with negative values for min-x and min-y. For example try <svg viewBox="0 -10 896 725" and remove the height attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you hover **Дети, Финансы**, it doesn't work well.
The paths scale when only if hovering over their stroke.
So I corrected it too.
This code can help you.

```
path:nth-child(2) {
  fill: white;
}
svg {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/George6/pen/PoKazyG)

Comment: thanks, you helped me a lot!